# react-router performs unexpectedly when clicking back button

Tags: javascript, react-router

i'm new to react,and this is just a part of my code.

About.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div > About < /div>
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        var elem = document.createElement("div");
        elem.innerText = "okokokkokoko";
        document.getElementById('app').appendChild(elem);
    }
})
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Router Tutorial</h1>
        <ul role="nav">
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/repos">Repos</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import App from './modules/App'
import About from './modules/About'
import Repos from './modules/Repos'

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

when i click the browser's back button on the About page,borwser will be back to the App page,but the page still retains the element

```
<div>okokokkokoko</div>
```

how can i solve this problem without changing the code of About.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is occurring because of the code in componentDidMount code

```
componentDidMount() {
        var elem = document.createElement("div");
        elem.innerText = "okokokkokoko";
        document.getElementById('app').appendChild(elem);
    }
```

Here after you load `/About` page, you are appending a div to the body with text `"okokokkokoko"`.
But after you got to `/App` page, you are not removing this  from the page. Thats why it remains there.

Actually it is bad practice and this is not how react should be used.

Instead change your `/About` code's render to following

```
render() {
        return (
           <div>
             <div > About < /div>
             <div>okokokokokoko</div>
           </div>
        )
    }
```

**Updated:** 
In that case the following solution might help you

```
componentDidMount() {
        document.getElementById('abc').innerText = "okokokkokoko";
    }
render() {
        return (
           <div>
             <div > About < /div>
             <div id="abc"></div>
           </div>
        )
    }
```

Here you are creating a  div in the current component. So when you will redirect to another route then the entire component (i.e. including your `<div>okokok</div>`) will also unmount.

Comment: it's just a test,i think that adding elements to `document` is unavoidable when using Third-party libraries like jqgrid,so i need  an approach to solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand React first. You can't create elements like this since React is unable to track them. Instead using "componentDidMount" use regular render.

```
render() {
    return <div> okokokkokoko</div>;
}
```

I highly recommend to go back to React docs and understand it.
https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html